# Alternative to .is(":hover")? Doesn't work in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, opera, jquery-events

See http://jsfiddle.net/cgWdF/3/

Works fine in every browser*, except the latest Opera.

*Haven't tested below IE9

Should have specified, It needs to return true or false, I'm not using it to bind an event.

Comment: jQuery's [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) handler wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I can't use .hover in an if statement, which is what i need.

Comment: Well, whatever you need it to do, you can use the `.data()` inside that handler and check against that data.

Comment: I don't get it all? Why can't you just bind a handler to the mouseover event. Why would you need to use a pseudo class for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) works in Opera 12.

```
var $sample = $("#sample");
$sample.hover(function() {
   $sample.css("background", "yellow");
}, function() {
    $sample.css("background", "");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cgWdF/4/)

Or, using [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the hovered status and test against it (similar to your original fiddle):

```
var $sample = $("#sample");
$sample.hover(function() {
   $(this).data('hovering', true);
}, function() {
   $(this).data('hovering', false);
});

setInterval(function(){
    var $sample = $("#sample");
    if($sample.data('hovering')) {
       $sample.css("background", "yellow");
    }
    else {
       $sample.css("background", "");
    }
}, 200);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cgWdF/5/)

Comment: Nicely done, I'd call `.off('hover')` before attaching a new hover handler to don't stack multiple hover events to the same element: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgWdF/10/), but performance-wise that shouldn't really matter until you hovered it a million of times without reloading the page. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use .mouseover() and .mouseout() to achieve the same effect. And if you want a delay on the animation, you can use .animate() in the jQuery UI

```
$('#sample').mouseover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                backgroundColor: "yellow"}, 200);
        });

$('#sample').mouseout(
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                backgroundColor: "#aaa"}, 200);
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cgWdF/8/

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.9.1, the other browsers have caught up with Opera - it doesn't work there any more either now. "it" being .is(":hover"), as investigated by your fiddle.

I wrote a workaround for .is(":hover"), see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mathheadinclouds/BxL4w/

```
function mouseIsOver(what){
    return $(what).is(":hover");
}
function mouseIsOverWorkaround(what){
    var temp = $(what).parent().find(":hover");
    return temp.length == 1 && temp[0] == what;
}
function mo(what){
    return document.getElementById("workaround").checked ? mouseIsOverWorkaround(what) : mouseIsOver(what);
}
setInterval(function(){
    var theBox = $("#theBox");
    if(mo(theBox[0])) {
       theBox.css("background", "yellow");
    } else {
       theBox.css("background", "");
    }
}, 200);
```

and the html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="workaround"/>
<div id="theBox"></div>
```